# Pyplot Line Connecting Two Circles

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have an array of x,y values that I got from a contour plot and I want to plot these values. Because it is a circle inside a circle pyplot draws an arbitrary line between the circles. Does anyone know of a way to remove this line?

I tried sorting the points which does not work. The only way I can think of removing this line is by manually moving the values to a new array and plotting them separately. However I have several of these cases and would prefer not to sift through every data point.

```
#Plotted contours of a variable
cs1 = ax1.contourf(x,z,refl0,clevs)

#Get the contour lines for the 10th contour of the plot
p1 = cs1.collections[10].get_paths()[0]
v = p1.vertices 
x1=v[:,0]
y1=v[:,1]

#Plot the contour lines
ax1 = plt.subplot(111)
ax1.plot(x1,y1)
```

[image]

Here is a generic example code

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x= np.arange(-100,100,10)
y= np.arange(-100,100,10)

#Make a random circular function
xi,yi = np.meshgrid(x,y)
z= 2*xi +xi**2 -yi +yi**2

#This is the contour plot of the data
ax = plt.subplot(111)
clevs = np.arange(-100,110,10)*100
cs1 = ax.contourf(xi,yi,z,clevs) 
plt.show()

#Get the contour lines for the 10th contour of the above plot
p1 = cs1.collections[11].get_paths()[0]
v = p1.vertices 
x1=v[:,0]
y1=v[:,1]

#Plot the contour lines
ax1 = plt.subplot(111)
ax1.plot(x1,y1)
plt.show()
```

Comment: My initial guess would be that you have to separate the datasets into individual arrays. If you have equal number of points for both circles, then you could to that relatively easily by indexing the array. Let me know and I can formulate a proper answer.

Comment: Unfortunately the circles do not have the same number of points and the number of points are not regularly spaced. I have 9 other arrays like this and they also have varying number of points for each circle.

Comment: Could you provide some more information please? I.e. what is `cs1.collections`, how do you generate the data points, what is `val`, etc ...

Comment: I added an example code which should work and a few comments.

Comment: Think about plotting the original contour map in a way that only shows the data of interest. For instance, give it a colormap that is white for every value not at your level of interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the aim is to draw two specific contour lines, you can simply select the levels in question and do a `contour` plot of them:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x= np.arange(-100,100,10)
y= np.arange(-100,100,10)

#Make a random circular function
xi,yi = np.meshgrid(x,y)
z= 2*xi +xi**2 -yi +yi**2

ax = plt.subplot(111)
clevs = np.arange(-100,110,10)*100
cs1 = ax.contourf(xi,yi,z,clevs) 

# chose level number 11 and 12 and draw them in black.
cs2 = ax.contour(xi,yi,z,clevs[11:13], colors="k") 

plt.show()
```

[image]